Consuming from a specific partition in single-broker, single-topic
I'm working with a Kafka setup that has a single broker and a single topic (3 partition). I want a specific consumer instance to only read messages from a designated partition within this topic.
Current code:
const { Kafka } = require('kafkajs');
const kafka = new Kafka({
  clientId: 'my-app',
  brokers: ['localhost:9092']
});

const consumer = kafka.consumer({ groupId: 'test-group' });

const buffer = [];

const run = async () => {
  await consumer.connect();
  await consumer.subscribe({ topic: 'Kafka_Test_Topic', fromBeginning: true });

  await consumer.run({
    eachMessage: async ({ topic, partition, message }) => {
      console.log({ value: message.value.toString()});
      }
    },
  });
};

run().catch(console.error);

I want this consumer to read messages from a designated partition.
Also, I want to know if i can achieve that producer is publishing on some partition and consumer is reading from other
How to achieve this using Kafkajs in Node.js?

Run 3 Nodejs processes, and each will automatically consume 1 partition. It's not good practice to explicitly consume from only one. And there's no problem with producers sending data to other partitions, so can you clarify the issue?

If you strictly want to consume from designated topic then search for function  similar to assign() which helps the consumer to connect to specific partition only.

You can create custom partitioner and partition assigner and write your own logic to achieve this. Below are the kafkajs interfaces for same.
const MyPartitioner = () => {
    return ({ topic, partitionMetadata, message }) => {
        // select a partition based on some logic
        // return the partition number
        return 0
    }
}

const MyPartitionAssigner = ({ cluster }) => ({
    name: 'MyPartitionAssigner',
    version: 1,
    async assign({ members, topics }) {},
    protocol({ topics }) {}
})

Here is an elaborate article on this.
